# FOREACH and UPDATE mysql not working together

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I can't seem to get this code to work. Can you run another query using the foreach rows? This is a cron script that will be sending out emails and I need to update the status from '0' to '1' when the cron runs so I know the emails were sent - the code **UPDATE query below does not work.**

```
// Connect to the database
$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$DB_HOST;dbname=$DB_DATABASE",$DB_USER,$DB_PASSWORD);

// Get the emails to send and ensure the status shows they have not been sent already
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT id, userid, title, message FROM reminders WHERE time=CURDATE() AND status='0'");
$stmt->execute();
$results = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

foreach($results AS $row){
echo $row['title'] . ' ' . $row['message'] . ' ' . $row['id'] . '<br />';
$update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE results SET status='1' WHERE id=:id");
$update->bindParam(':id', $row['id']);
$update->execute();
};
```

EDIT: The table name was wrong. Solved

Comment: Does that throws a MySql error or what?

Comment: It displays the correct row but does not update the status column. No errors are displayed

Comment: try removing quotes from status ='1' to status = 1.status may be an int column I guess.

Comment: techie_28 mysql converts string to int like a charm. This will not help.

Comment: Is the table you want to update really named "results" or has this information creeped in from the name of he results variable? (just to make sure)

Comment: mscflause show us your table structure, we need more info

Comment: F*** I am an idiot. 1 hour of my life gone.. I was specifying the wrong table (results should be reminders)

Comment: Thought so... ;o) We all do this from time to time...

Comment: Thanks guys! sorry for the waste of time :(

Comment: @Leigh "Sorry, this question has answers and cannot be deleted; flag it for moderator attention instead"

Comment: iirc, but says flag, but still allows you to delete,

Comment: Actually I would keep this. Its a valid question - and reminds people to double check. Which is a valid reminder.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

how about specifying the datatype of the value (*I think [not sure] the default data type is string and the server automatically parses it*)? `PDO::PARAM_INT`

```
$update->bindValue(':id', $row['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
```

**[PDO Predefine Constants](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.constants.php)**

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you need to `bindValue` and specify the datatype:

```
$update = $conn->prepare("UPDATE results SET status=1 WHERE id=:id");
$update->bindValue(':id', $row['id'], PDO::PARAM_INT);
$update->execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to have the correct solution in the question - answer format:

You are using the result variable `resuls` and then try to update the table `results`. Is the table you want to update really named "results" or has this information creeped in from the name of the variable?

From the query it look like you are working on the table `reminders`.